# How do aliases or redirects work?

Tags: domains, redirects, subdomain, cpanel

Is it possible that I set-up a redirect of my store which is located at www.xyz.com/store to store.xyz.com .

Do i have to buy a new domain name or is there any other way.

Comment: "aliases or redirects" - "aliases" and "redirects" can mean something very different. Your question would seem to be referring to a "redirect", not an "alias".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You most certainly do not have to buy store.xyz.com as a new domain name. store.xyz.com is a part of xyz.com

A domain name is made up of multiple parts

**www.google.com**

```
www.google.com
 |    |     | --- domain name extension 
 |    | --- domain name
 | --- subdomain
```

**mail.google.com**

```
mail.google.com
 |     |     | --- domain name extension 
 |     | --- domain name
 | --- subdomain
```

Your ownership of the domain name entitles you to unlimited subdomains, but your webhost may choose not to let you create them. (In fact, you already have one subdomain, **www**.xyz.com) Your web host / domain name registrar may also attempt to trick you into paying for subdomains.

The specifics of how to set up a subdomain vary depending on your hosting configuration.

For GoDaddy:

> - Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Manage.
> - In the Domains section, click Subdomains.
> - Complete the following fields, and then click Create:
>
>   - Subdomain — Enter the subdomain you want to use for one of your hosted domain names.
>   - Select the domain name for which you want to create the subdomain.
>   - Document Root — Enter the directory you want to use as the root directory for the subdomain's website, or use cPanel's default.

Quoting Godaddy's page on [Managing Your Hosting Account Subdomains](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4652/managing-your-hosting-account-subdomains)

(For other people who see this answer other than the OP and are not on GoDaddy): To redirect /store to this subdomain , see the other answers.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the doubts about domain and sub domain.

Comment: I bought my web hosting from GoDaddy.

Domain name from GoDaddy.

Starter Linux hosting with cPanel.

I didn't buy them together but separately.

Comment: OK. I am busy now, but I try to get back to you later today

Comment: @AbhiAvana Alright, I updated my answer with GoDaddy specific instructions.

Comment: Domain/Subdomain is more complicated than that. If I give you `www.sante.gouv.fr`,  what is the domain and the subdomain? Same for just `dk` (try in your browser, it works), or `www.springfield.k12.or.us`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest ways to do a redirect in order from the old-fashioned method to the best method is as follows:

**Code snippet 1**

saved as index.html in the document root of the old URL.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirecting</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=http://store.xyz.com">
</head>
<body>
<p>Loading new page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It works but the experience is rather slow because the digit in the content value of the meta tag is the number of seconds before the refresh actually happens.

**Code snippet 2**

saved as index.html in the document root of the old URL.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirecting</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Loading new page</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href="http://store.xyz.com";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This method is faster, but the user needs javascript enabled in their browser.

**Code snippet 3**

saved as index.php in the document root of the old URL.

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently",true);
header("Location: http://store.xyz.com",true);
?><html>
<head>
<title>Redirecting</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Loading new page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In this last snippet, I did add extra HTML but most browsers would pick up the HTTP headers and automatically do the redirection quickly.

Pick any snippet and add a link pointing to the new URL just incase the automatic redirection does not work in any particular web browser. Some web browsers can be very buggy.

Comment: The problem is, they are asking to how acquire store.xyz.com and then host the content of /store at store.xyz.com. How are you answering their question at all? Downvoting

Comment: The other steps to the process has been answered by other users. I'm adding a very important step to complete the process. Without this step, no redirects will take place.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know that was acceptable, but you have much higher rep than me so I will assume that you are knowledgeable about this.

Comment: I run a website myself and had to do numerous of redirects on some URLs when I change the URL in order to make it friendlier, and to prevent 404 errors on pages that are just in another location, and to rank well in search engines.

Comment: Ok. I am still not sure about this, so I asked a question on meta. Just wanted to let you know that it is at http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/other-user-answers-question-with-answer-that-only-convers-a-relativly-small-thin

Comment: @DanielF The down vote was a bit excessive considering that both answers address half of the problem. It would be okay to rescind the down-vote. We have all down-voted and rescinded once an answer was improved. Comments are better. It is common here to chuck in what we know since we each have our expertise. I often reference other answers in my own answer to make a complete solution for the OP. That way it is clear that I an giving a nod to the other users contribution and agree with it. There are a ton of very good people here and this is a far gentler population than many other SE sites.

Comment: @DanielF I am sure your intent is a good one. Please continue to participate here and I think you will see what I particularly like about this group of folks- they are fantastic!! I am sure you will make a good member of the group!

Comment: @closetnoc Thank you! I look forward to learning more about how to behave on stackexchange. I forgot that I downvoted yesterday, or I would have upvoted today after I ready the response on meta. I have upvoted now.

Comment: @DanielF Your a good man! See? I was right!! ;-) You will do well here I am sure! Like I said, this really is a good group of folks. Occasionally we get a dud, but they are often repelled by the goodness polarity. For whatever reason, it seems that webmasters are amazingly giving people. I have always liked them. Being here, I can prove my point with actual stats on the subject. Cheers!!

Comment: Sometimes answers are well formed by multiple people. Its like putting the missing pieces of the puzzle together to form the grand solution. Ok. Now this comment may deserve a -1 for not being on topic to the question.

Comment: "Pick any snippet" - Should just add, that whilst **Code snippet 1 & 2** will redirect a _user_, they are a last resort (ie. not to be recommended) as they don't return the correct 3xx HTTP Status Code to the client - so _bots_ might not see it. Since this would appear to be an "existing store", this last step could be very important.

Answer (score -2):

For the sake of SEO, and maintaining your pages' rank, you may want to permanently redirect the old URLs to the new ones. Here's the [Google documentation on redirects](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en).

Comment: You don't really answer the question.

Comment: This might have been better as a comment to one of the other answers. You are right in your comment. A 301 redirect is best and it appears that point was not made. I often update an answer I have written based upon a comment and give a nod to the user for their contribution in case the comment is later deleted. Thanks for chucking in! Cheers!!

Comment: Sueneu, The OP wanted to actually implement a redirect between two domains, but the answer you presented explains why redirecting is better.

Comment: Mike, glad to help, Zistoloen, would adding this as a comment to another answer have been appropriate?